# Unity Editor window panes flicker when running in Hyper V

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, windows-10, game-development, hyper-v

I'm running Unity inside of a HyperV virtual machine (VM), where the host and VM are both running Windows 10. When using Enhanced Mode, Unity's windows will flicker to solid black:

[image: GIF of Unity inspector windows flickering]

I so far haven't seen the issue in any other software running in the VM. I also don't see the problem when running in Basic Mode. While normally I use Basic Mode, I frequently need to use Enhanced Mode to allow USB devices connected to the host to passthru to the VM.

I've reproduced this in both Unity 2021.3.9 and 2021.3.12.

How do I fix this?